# How to use ContainerResponseWriter in Jersey 2

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0

This concept is also present in Jersey 1. In can be used in response filter the following way:

response.setContainerResponseWriter

So the question is how to use it in Jersey 2. I can't find any example and also in java docs it's present as a kind of standalone feature. I need a way to do the same in filter using Jersey 2 but ContainerResponseContext has no relation to ResponseWriter.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

There are several implementation of [ContainerResponseWriter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/spi/ContainerResponseWriter.html), particularly in containers:

- default: [FutureResponseWriter](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ApplicationHandler.java#L925)
- servlet: [ResponseWriter](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/internal/ResponseWriter.java#L74)
- jetty: [ResponseWriter](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/containers/jetty-http/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/jetty/JettyHttpContainer.java#L246)
- ...

What exactly do you need `ContainerResponseWriter` for? (especially why do you need it's functionality in a filter?)

Comment: It's a metering filter - how many active requests etc. Like I said I'm trying to upgrade it to Jersey 2 with functionality preserved.